# Type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, fortran, intel-fortran

I have some demonstrative Fortran code (which is supposed to be successfully compiled) and try to compile in Intel Visual Fortran + VS2013. But I got an error during compilation

```
 error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument
```

It seems the code in line 6 has some problem, but I cannot figure it out exactly

Aside: I can compile this code successfully within command line, so it's highly possible due to Visual studio setting. But I cannot figure out which option is responsible. Some solution suggest disabling the `Check Routine Interface` option, but it seems too dangerous.

```
SUBROUTINE FUNARR (A,N)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER:: N
        REAL,DIMENSION(N):: A

        WRITE(*,*)"FUNARR VECTOR SUBSCRIPT....IN"
        WRITE(*,'(10F12.6)')A(:N)
        WRITE(*,*)"FUNARR VECTOR SUBSCRIPT....OUT"
        A(:N)=A(:N)-100

    END SUBROUTINE

    PROGRAM WWW_FCODE_CN
        IMPLICIT NONE

        INTEGER,PARAMETER:: NMAX=100
        REAL,PARAMETER:: PI=3.14159265
        REAL,DIMENSION(NMAX):: ARR
        INTEGER,DIMENSION(5):: VECSUBSCP=(/1,4,6,7,5/)
        INTEGER:: NARR,I

        NARR=10

        ARR=1.
        ARR(:NARR)=1.   
        WRITE(*,*)"ASSIGN TOTAL"
        WRITE(*,'(10F12.6)')ARR(:NARR)
        WRITE(*,*)

        ARR(1)=-1.
        WRITE(*,*)"ASSIGN ELEMENT"
        WRITE(*,'(10F12.6)')ARR(:NARR)
        WRITE(*,*)

        ARR(2:4)=(/(SIN(PI*(I-1.)/(NARR-1)),I=2,4)/)
        WRITE(*,*)"ASSIGN SLICE"
        WRITE(*,'(10F12.6)')ARR(:NARR)
        WRITE(*,*)

        CALL FUNARR(ARR(2:4),3)
        WRITE(*,*)"FUNARR SLICE"
        WRITE(*,'(10F12.6)')ARR(:NARR)
        WRITE(*,*)

        ARR(VECSUBSCP(:3))=0.5
        WRITE(*,*)"ASSIGN VECTOR SUBSCRIPT"
        WRITE(*,'(10F12.6)')ARR(:NARR)
        WRITE(*,*)

    ! ACTUAL ARGUMENT IS AN ARRAY SECTION WITH A VECTOR SUBSCRIPT
    ! DISCONTINUE,COPY,UNKNOWN POSITION,CANNOT BE INTENT(OUT)
        CALL FUNARR(ARR(VECSUBSCP(3:5)),3)
        WRITE(*,*)"FUNARR VECTOR SUBSCRIPT"
        WRITE(*,'(10F12.6)')ARR(:NARR)
        WRITE(*,*)

        STOP

    END PROGRAM WWW_FCODE_CN
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with `gfortran`.

Comment: I highly suspect that it's due to some unintentional action on visual studio option, but I cannot find which is responsible for this

Comment: Do you have the option of compiling with a command line tool? I think you should have access to `ifort`, which does not show any problem with the code (version 11) either, similar to gfortran.

Comment: YES，it can be compiled without any problem

Comment: Is it possible that VS-2013 performs interface checking for   FUNARR() (having implicit interface), assumes the dummy argument A(N) to have intent(inout), and thinks it conflicts with the actual argument of FUNARR() with vector subscript (which is an array temporary with intent(in))...? (And I'm wondering which is "line 6".)

Comment: None of the currently supported Windows x64 version of ifort are giving me this problem, even with /warn:interfaces turned on.  Some past version of ifort may have exhibited such a bug with this rather unusual usage of a sequence of array sections.  So, if you must use an old version, you might consider the advice of turning off that check.

Comment: Note that an array section with a vector subscript, which appear a few times in your program, cannot be associated with a dummy argument that is defined or redefined (F2008 6.5.3.3.2p2).  Execution of the line `CALL FUNARR(ARR(VECSUBSCP(3:5)),3)` will be non-conforming.